# Panda3D: How to orient BulletGenericConstraint?

Tags: bulletphysics, panda3d

By default, the **BulletGenericConstraint** in **Panda3D** is oriented along positive X axis. The **setAngularLimit** method can be used to set only along X, Y or Z axis.  How do I join two bodies which do not lie orthogonal to any of the axis by a BulletGenericConstraint?

That is, how do I **orient** a BulletGenericConstraint in a direction along an arbitrary vector, which is not along X, Y or Z axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BulletGenericConstraint takes two 'frame' arguments, each being a TransformState object.  I believe you can use these to specify a relative rotation between the two bodies being affected by the constraint.

The TransformState interface is a bit tricky to work with, but it's easy to use once you get the hang of it.  Transform states use a special kind of cache that causes them to be immutable.  Every setX operation you perform on it does not modify the object, but instead returns a new TransformState object with the requested operation applied.

It is perhaps easiest to use a TransformState object that has already been applied on a node, using `getTransform()`, `getNetTransform()`, or `getTransform(otherNode)`.  Or, you can construct a TransformState object from a translation and a set of HPR angles:

```
ts = TransformState.makePosHpr(pos, hpr)
```